# Change object shape using animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to change circular shape of an object to a custom clip path using animation.

Is it possible to change this shape:

```
Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
   color: Color.fromRGBO(13, 58, 94, 1)
  )
)
```

to this shape:

```
child: ClipPath(
  clipper: clipper,
  child: Container(
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    color: Color.fromRGBO(13, 58, 94, 1),
 ),
)
```

where clipper is:

```
@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    final double _xScaling = size.width / 50;
    final double _yScaling = size.height / 50;
    path.lineTo(41.21 * _xScaling,0 * _yScaling);
    path.cubicTo(41.21 * _xScaling,0 * _yScaling,41.21 * _xScaling,8.68 * _yScaling,41.21 * _xScaling,8.68 * _yScaling,);
    path.cubicTo(41.21 * _xScaling,8.68 * _yScaling,4.210000000000001 * _xScaling,8.68 * _yScaling,4.210000000000001 * _xScaling,8.68 * _yScaling,);
    path.cubicTo(1.8784258021338358 * _xScaling,8.658054710658401 * _yScaling,-0.00010327465861241198 * _xScaling,6.761677470237657 * _yScaling,0 * _xScaling,4.43 * _yScaling,);
    path.cubicTo(-0.004978909916987346 * _xScaling,4.3500774670713005 * _yScaling,-0.004978909916987327 * _xScaling,4.269922532928699 * _yScaling,0 * _xScaling,4.1899999999999995 * _yScaling,);
    path.cubicTo(0.18293766028633673 * _xScaling,1.8240900455755096 * _yScaling,2.1570287122131537 * _xScaling,-0.0018350300172383263 * _yScaling,4.53 * _xScaling,0 * _yScaling,);
    path.cubicTo(4.53 * _xScaling,0 * _yScaling,41.21 * _xScaling,0 * _yScaling,41.21 * _xScaling,0 * _yScaling,);
    return path;
  }
```

using animation?

Here is the picture of the shapes

[image]

Comment: see how [RoundedRectangleBorder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f9c825981c/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/rounded_rectangle_border.dart#L28) do that - pay special attention to `lerpFrom` and `lerpTo` methods

Comment: I have been trying to get that work, but I had no success. Could you please provide some code sample?

Comment: code sample of how to animate shape morphing?

Comment: Yes, preferably with RoundedRectangleBorder which you mentioned

Comment: Oh yeah, now we come to the second problem I had and that is that I need to change the width direction, and if I try with something like TextDirection it would not work because of the offset that I have to use in this animation. This circle that you see on the picture starts in the middle and then offsets to the point where it is positioned on the picture and then should morph into the other shape. By default, flutter in this scenario widens the object to the left instead of what I need and that is to the right.

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: I will edit the question in some near future, thank you for your help

Comment: but of course, instead of using `AnimatedContainer` / `Material` and a custom `ShapeBorder` you can explicitly use `AnimationController` and some kind of `AnimatedBuilder` / `AnimatedWidget` / etc